# How to change color of a listview's item and keep it unchaged until another item clicked from that listview android?

Tags: android, listview

How to change the color of the list-view and keep it unchanged until another item clicked from that list-view?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

       List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

            hm.put("ICONIMG", Integer.toString(drwbl_imgs[i]) );   
            hm.put("TITLE",str_tit[i]);
            aList.add(hm);        
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "ICONIMG","TITLE"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.img_listicon,R.id.txtvw_slidebar_listview};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.child_slidebar_listview_layout, from, to);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
  <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" >

    </ListView>
```

**child_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_listview_lay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#808080"

     >


 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_listicon"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"


    />


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtvw_slidebar_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left|center"
    android:text=""
    />

     </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give selector to list item.

left_menu_list_seletor.xml:

```
    <item android:drawable="@color/listItemSelectedItemBgColor" android:state_activated="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/listItemSelectedItemBgColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/listItemColor"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/listItemColor" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

You can specify colors in colors.xml file

Add background attribute to your child_layout like     `android:background="@drawable/left_menu_list_seletor"`

Dont forget to add choice mode to listview

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: You could add android:choiceMode="singleChoice" to the XML to save on Java code

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you meant by 'color of Listview' do you mean the background color of the listview or background color of a listview item ?

Assuming you want to set the background color of the selected list item here is my answer.

1. Declare this variable in your activity class:

   private View mPrevSelectedSong;
2. Write onListItemClick method like below inside Activities onCreate():

   ```
   mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View view,
               final int pos, long arg3)
       {
               mLocationClientHandler.animateMapToOffer(pos);
               if (mPrevSelectedSong != null)
                   mPrevSelectedSong.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
               //view.setSelected(true);
               view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#669ab311"));//any color code that you want to set for selected state
               mPrevSelectedSong = view;
       }
   });
   ```

Hope this solves your problem...

Comment: The solution doesn't need any Java.